# Given a Tree generate its Prüfer Code

Tags: code-golf, graph-theory

In [graph-theory](/questions/tagged/graph-theory) a [Prüfer code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%BCfer_sequence) is a unique sequence of integers that denotes a specific tree.

You can find the Prüfer code of a tree with the following algorithm taken from Wikipedia:

> Consider a labeled tree T with vertices `{1, 2, ..., n}`. At step *i*, remove the leaf with the smallest label and set the *i*th element of the Prüfer sequence to be the label of this leaf's neighbor.

(Note that since it's a leaf it will only have one neighbor).

You should stop the iteration when only two vertices remain in the graph.

## Task

Given a labeled tree as input output its Prüfer code.  You may take input in any reasonable manner.  Such as an adjacency matrix or your languages builtin graph representation. (*You may not take input as a Prüfer code*).

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so you should aim to minimize the bytes in your source.

## Test cases

Here are some inputs in ASCII with their outputs below.  You do not need to support ASCII input like this.

```
    3
    |
1---2---4---6
    |
    5

{2,2,2,4}
```

---

```
1---4---3
    |
5---2---6---7
|
8

{4,4,2,6,2,5}
```

---

```
5---1---4   6
    |       |
    2---7---3

{1,1,2,7,3}
```

Comment: Can we take in a rooted tree as input?

Comment: Can we take input as something like `[[2,1],[2,3],[2,5],[2,4,6]]` for the first case? (i.e. each branch)

Comment: @xnor Yes you can

Comment: I feel like taking an input with edges or paths directed towards a root is  precomputation towards the Prüfer Code. Either way, I think you should be clearer on "You may take input in any reasonable manner (You may not take input as a Prüfer code)."

Comment: @xnor Oh I didn't understand what Hyper Neutrino was asking.

Comment: @WheatWizard My rooted tree question also goes in that direction, since each vertex points upwards towards the root.

Comment: @xnor I think a rooted tree is alright, It is a pretty standard way of representing trees and it doesn't give you that much of an advantage.

Comment: @HyperNeutrino Did you assume there is only 4 branches?

Comment: @LeakyNun No. The reason I deleted my answer is because my input format made finding the leaves trivial.

Comment: @HyperNeutrino I'm not referring to your deleted answer.

Comment: @AnderBiguri, because the fourth node deleted is the `2` and it's adjacent to the `4`.

Comment: @LeakyNun Oh, sorry. In that case still, I'm not assuming anything about the number of branches.

Comment: @HyperNeutrino How would you represent subbranches?

Comment: @LeakyNun Every leaf has a unique path from the root node. Thus, we represent the tree by a list of all paths to the leaf. But that presents an unfair advantage to me because the leaves are precalculated.

Comment: @HyperNeutrino I wouldn't say that it is unfair. It is in essence what a tree is. But good luck finding common branches.

Comment: @LeakyNun My deleted answer did that using a strange method (though it is still over twice the length of the other valid Python answer).

Answer (score 9):

## Mathematica, 34 bytes

```
<<Combinatorica`
LabeledTreeToCode
```

Somebody had to do it....

After loading the `Combinatorica` package, the function `LabeledTreeToCode` expects a tree input as an undirected graph with explicitly listed edges and vertices; for example, the input in the second test case could be `Graph[{{{1, 4}}, {{4, 3}}, {{4, 2}}, {{2, 5}}, {{2, 6}}, {{6, 7}}, {{5, 8}}}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}]`.

Comment: Of course there's a built-in to do this. >_>

Answer (score 4):

## Python 3, <s>136</s> <s>131</s> 127 bytes

```
def f(t):
 while len(t)>2:
  m=min(x for x in t if len(t[x])<2);yield t[m][0];del t[m]
  for x in t:m in t[x]and t[x].remove(m)
```

Takes input as an adjacency matrix. First example:

```
>>> [*f({1:[2],2:[1,3,4,5],3:[2],4:[2,6],5:[2],6:[4]})]
[2, 2, 2, 4]
```

Comment: well I failed...

Comment: @HyperNeutrino You were about 4 seconds faster!

Comment: Hehe yup! And about 2.7 times as long! :D gg

Comment: You could probably avoid naming your function `pruefer`

Comment: @WheatWizard Right. Still testing and golfing.

Comment: `del` exists? >_>

Comment: Now it actually works in all cases.

Comment: You can use spaces for single indent and tabs for double.  There are also some places you could use semicolons.

Comment: @WheatWizard You're right about the semicolons, but mixing tabs and spaces is an error in Python 3.

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 31 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
FĠLÞḢḢ
0ịµÇHĊṙ@µÇCịṪ,
WÇÐĿḢ€ṖṖḊ
```

A monadic link which takes a list of pairs of nodes (defining the edges) in any order (and each in any orientation) and returns the Prüfer Code as a list.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@@92ZIHP4XkPdywCIi6Dh7u7D2093O5xpOvhzpkOIKYzUOjhzlU6XOGH2w9POLIfqOxR05qHO6eB0I6u////R0cb6pjE6kSb6BiDSSMgaQomjXTMgKSZjjlYxCI2FgA)**

#### How?

```
FĠLÞḢḢ - Link 1, find leaf location: list of edges (node pairs)
F      - flatten
 Ġ     - group indices by value (sorted smallest to largest by value)
  LÞ   - sort by length (stable sort, so equal lengths remain in prior order)
    ḢḢ - head head (get the first of the first group. If there are leaves this yields
       -   the index of the smallest leaf in the flattened version of the list of edges)

0ịµÇHĊṙ@µÇCịṪ, - Link 2, separate smallest leaf: list with last item a list of edges
0ị             - item at index zero - the list of edges
  µ            - monadic chain separation (call that g)
   Ç           - call last link (1) as a monad (index of smallest leaf if flattened)
    H          - halve
     Ċ         - ceiling (round up)
      ṙ@       - rotate g left by that amount (places the edge to remove at the right)
        µ      - monadic chain separation (call that h)
         Ç     - call last link (1) as a monad (again)
          C    - complement (1-x)
            Ṫ  - tail h (removes and yields the edge)
           ị   - index into, 1-based and modular (gets the other node of the edge)
             , - pair with the modified h
               -    (i.e. [otherNode, restOfTree], ready for the next iteration)

WÇÐĿḢ€ṖṖḊ - Main link: list of edges (node pairs)
W         - wrap in a list (this is so the first iteration works)
  ÐĿ      - loop and collect intermediate results until no more change:
 Ç        -   call last link (2) as a monad
    Ḣ€    - head €ach (get the otherNodes, although the original tree is also collected)
      ṖṖ  - discard the two last results (they are excess to requirements)
        Ḋ - discard the first result (the tree, leaving just the Prüfer Code)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 29 bytes

```
[Dg#ÐD˜{γé¬`U\X.å©Ï`XK`ˆ®_Ï]¯
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@x/tkq58eILL6TnV5zYfXnloTUJoTITe4aWHVh7uT4jwTjjddmhd/OH@2EPr//@PjjbRMY7ViTbVMQKSRjpmQNJQxwRImumYA0kTsLipjkVsLAA)

**Explanation**

```
[Dg#                           # loop until only 1 link (2 vertices) remain
    ÐD                         # quadruple the current list of links
      ˜{                       # flatten and sort values
        γé                     # group by value and order by length of runs
          ¬`U                  # store the smallest leaf in X
             \X                # discard the sorted list and push X
               .å©             # check each link in the list if X is in that link
                  Ï`           # keep only that link
                    XK`ˆ       # add the value that isn't X to the global list
                        ®_Ï    # remove the handled link from the list of links
                           ]   # end loop
                            ¯  # output global list
```

Answer (score 1):

### Clojure, 111 bytes

```
#(loop[r[]G %](if-let[i(first(sort(remove(set(vals G))(keys G))))](recur(conj r(G i))(dissoc G i))(butlast r)))
```

Requires the input to be a hash-map, having "leaf-like" labels as keys and "root-like" labels as values. For example:

```
{1 2, 3 2, 5 2, 4 2, 6 4}
{1 4, 3 4, 4 2, 8 5, 5 2, 7 6, 6 2}
```

On each iteration it finds the smallest key which is not referenced by any other node, adds it to the result `r` and removes the node from the graph definition `G`. `if-let` goes to else case when `G` is empty, as `first` returns `nil`. Also the last element has to be dropped.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 91 bytes

```python
d=input()
while len(d)>2:m=min(d,key=lambda k:len(d[k]));n,=d[m];del d[m];d[n]-={m};print n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#JYnBCsMgEAXv/QqPEbaHGJODYn9EPCQoVNQllIRSZL/dBnMZZt5r3kTcz2Pgj@875sBywMHzl1DFlHgppPAzeS2bX1lS/bXJca4RjLfFaR8yu8Wie5paSO@fiAfD1uqoqiAQqo4wgYSZYOqLvAgLwdxrUVUS/QE)

Based on [L3viathan's solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/120164/20260). Takes a dictionary of sets representing adjacency lists.